# Image not loaded in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I have a UIViewcontoroller subclass and the following code is in my viewdidload ,

```
CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cellFrame ]  ;
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"]];
self.view=myImageView;
[super viewDidLoad];
```

The image file is in the same directory as the class files. The issue is when the app is loaded the image is not shown just a blank screen.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check if `[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"]` is returning a nil?

Comment: there might be the capitalization problem with the name check the name of the file is @"First.png" and you are using @"first.png"?

Comment: the file name is correct. No case issues. However when i open the file it is showing 'Locked' on the pic preview. Could that be the issue ? I have used the same png file on a tab bar button and there was no issue there.

Comment: no it is not related to locked, I have written the same code in a test project and it works fine for me `- (void)viewDidLoad {
    
    UIImageView *imgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)];
    [imgview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sound.png"]];
    self.view = imgview;
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
}
`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Very strange. I have renamed the file and retried but it still does not work. Can you please confirm where the app will look for the file. currently i have it in the same folder as where the class resides.

Comment: The issue is that the [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] is returning nil. Why would it return nil ?

Comment: it does not really matter where is the physical location of your file until it is added in the project. when you compile, every resource is copied to the bundle directly. so if the image is showing at some other place in the UI it ought to show up here also. I think you need to confirm the imagename that you have set for your  tabbar - just to double check.

Comment: the only reason of `imageNamed` returning a nil is due to unable to locate file in bundle resource. is it in some folder in the project which appear to be of "blue" color instead of "yellow"?

Comment: When i said I have used the same png file on a tab bar button that was in another project and i do not have it in this project.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. As you may have noted i am a bit of a newbie to iPhone programming. My assumption was if i added the physical file to the folder the image will load but i also have to add it to the project. Issue solved.

Comment: just remove the image from your project and add it again - do this by "add existing file".

Answer (score 2):

**1.Instead of `self.view=myImageView;` use `[self.view addSubview:myImageView];`**

1.Also`[super viewDidLoad];` call this first before any statement.

3.Then check if the `[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"]` is returning image.

4.Also check `first.png` is the name of the file.Note names are case sensitive for devices.

Comment: Thanks. The issue seems that the [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"] is returning nil. I have no idea why. The file name and extension is correct.